# Tomcat не стартует с помощью файла catalina.bat В чём тут дело?

Tags: tomcat

Скачал и распаковал Tomcat.

При попытке запуска с помощью файла catalina.bat консоль Tomcat появляется лишь на мгновение и тут же исчезает. Tomcat не стартует.

При попытке запуска с помощью файла startup.bat консоль Tomcat появляется и не исчезает. Tomcat стартует, стартовая страница Tomcat  по адресу http://localhost:8080/ открывается.

apache-tomcat-9.0.27
Windows 10

В чём тут дело, почему не работает с catalina.bat?

В консоли:

```
C:\java\apache-tomcat-9.0.27\bin>catalina.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\java\apache-tomcat-9.0.27"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\java\apache-tomcat-9.0.27"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\java\apache-tomcat-9.0.27\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\java\apache-tomcat-9.0.27\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\java\apache-tomcat-9.0.27\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Usage:  catalina ( commands ... )
commands:
  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger
  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager
  jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger
  run               Start Catalina in the current window
  run -security     Start in the current window with security manager
  start             Start Catalina in a separate window
  start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager
  stop              Stop Catalina
  configtest        Run a basic syntax check on server.xml
  version           What version of tomcat are you running?
```

Comment: пробовали смотреть что в консоли то пишется?

Comment: консоль Tomcat появляется лишь на мгновение и тут же исчезает -- не успеваешь ничего прочитать...

Comment: добавьте pause в конце батника или запустите его из cmd

Comment: читать пытались что написано? необходимо батнику передать команду действия, например  `catalina.bat start`

Comment: Двойной щелчок мышкой по файлу catalina.bat -- разве это не аналог команды "start" ? 
Двойной щелчок мышкой по файлу startup.bat срабатывает же. 
В чём разница?

Comment: есть команда start у os windows, она запускает процесс, тут команда start - это аргумент, который интерпретирует catalina.bat, почитайте его код и увидите это там

Comment: То есть стартовать Tomcat с помощью файла startup.bat можно и двойным щелчком мыши по файлу и командой start из консоли,
а стартовать Tomcat с помощью файла catalina.bat можно только командой start из консоли
?

Comment: startup.bat выполняет это за Вас, передает аргумент start на вход catalina.bat : https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/bin/startup.bat

Comment: Stranger in the Q, Спасибо за помощь!